# How to install pytorch 0.3 on windows wsl 2

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to install pytorch 0.3 with gpu support on windows wsl 2 (Ubuntu-20.04)? I tried wheels for older versions of pytorch in this link https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/ but could not get a workable solution.

I tried `pip install torch-0.3.0.post4-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl` command but it gives `ERROR: torch-0.3.0.post4-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` as an error. I am using conda and python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

After trying numerous ways, It turns out that minimum CUDA version supported by my GPU is not compatible with the PyTorch 0.3. I have a RTX 2080s GPU, which has Turing architecture with compute capability of 7.5 and supports CUDA 10. However, there is no prebuilt binary of PyTorch 0.3 that is compiled against CUDA 10. (Old version can be reached via official PyTorch website) So, if there is no binary compiled against your target CUDA version in PyTorch, one must need to build from source of PyTorch. When I tried to build PyTorch 0.3 from source, it hit an error and cannot be built. Then, at this stage, It  turn out that PyTorch 0.3 itself is not compatible with CUDA 10 and above versions. However, I successfully run my code written in Pytorch 0.3 in Google Colab because GPU that the colab gives you is Tesla K80 which has CUDA 9. There is a PyTorch binary built against CUDA 9. So it is possible to run code in colab. But if you want to run such a code in newer GPUs, I am afraid to say that it is not possible. Only solution is switching to a newer version of Pytorch that supports new GPUs.

Further reading about problem can be found here.
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-0-3-build-from-source-with-cuda-10-cmake-error-cuda-cublas-device-library-advanced/135117